# How do I add a custom body class for a specific page ID?

Tags: post-class

I have added this code to my child theme's `functions.php` file and use the new class but it styles the entire site, not the page I added to the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
add_filter('body_class','custom_body_class');

function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if( is_page('38034') ) {
        $classes[] = 'new-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code returns an error: > Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\Users\brad\Desktop\InstantWP_4.3\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 393
 class="">

Comment: the `return $classes;` would need to be outside of the `if( is_page() )`

Answer (score 8):

The ID can/should be given without quotes (otherwise if you a page with '38034' as slug/post_name, this will be used instead of the page with the ID 38034). And you want to `return $classes` no matter if you added your own or not.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if (is_page(38034))
        $classes[] = 'new-class';
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function name does not match. Try this..

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );

function custom_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page( '38034' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'new-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed that which was my mistake but i still get this error > Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\Users\brad\Desktop\InstantWP_4.3\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 393
 class="">

Comment: Where are you adding this code? Try adding it to your functions.php file.